# Why I am getting Time Limit Exceeded in Java?

Tags: java

**Input**

The input begins with the number **t** of test cases in a single line `(t<=10)`. In each of the next **t** lines there are two numbers **m** and **n** `(1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000)` separated by a space.

**Output**

For every test case print all prime numbers **p** such that `m <= p <= n`, one number per line, test cases separated by an empty line.

**Example**
**Input:**

```
2
1 10
3 5
```

**Output:**

```
2
3
5
7

3
5
```

As i declare it. I solved this question but i am trying to upload the solution for one site but i am getting time limit exceeded.I didn't figure it out to optimizing.

Could anyone help? Thank you.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = s.nextInt();
        int flag = 0;
        int arr[][] = new int[t][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = s.nextInt();
            }
        }
        for (int a = 0; a < t; a++) {
            for (int b = arr[a][0]; b <= arr[a][1]; b++) {
                if (b < 2) {
                    b = 2;
                }
                for (int c = 2; c < b; c++) {
                    if (b % c == 0) {
                        flag = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (flag == 0) {
                    System.out.println(b);
                } else {
                    flag = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should look up some faster ways of generating primes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good, but have one problem at for (int c = 2; c < b; c++).

The simplest primality test is trial division: Given an input number n, check whether any prime integer m from 2 to √n evenly divides n (the division leaves no remainder). If n is divisible by any m then n is composite, otherwise, it is prime.

For example, to test the primality of 100 by trial division, consider all the integer divisors of 100:

2, 4, 5, 10, 20, 25, 50
The largest factor is 100/2 = 50. This is true for all n: all divisors are less than or equal to n/2. Inspecting the divisors, it is determined that some of them are redundant. The list of divisors may be written as:

100 = 2 × 50 = 4 × 25 = 5 × 20 = 10 × 10 = 20 × 5 = 25 × 4 = 50 × 2
which demonstrates the redundancy. Once the divisor 10 is tested, which is √100, the first divisor is simply the dividend of a previous divisor. Therefore, testing divisors greater than √n can be eliminated. All the even numbers are greater than 2 can also be eliminated, since if an even number can divide so can 2.

Source Wikipedia [Primalty test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test).

SO a small modification in your code can improve running time many folds.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = s.nextInt();
    int flag = 0;
    int arr[][] = new int[t][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = s.nextInt();
        }
    }
    for (int a = 0; a < t; a++) {
        for (int b = arr[a][0]; b <= arr[a][1]; b++) {
            if (b < 2) {
                b = 2;
            }
            for (int c = 2; c*c <= b; c++) {
                if (b % c == 0) {
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (flag == 0) {
                System.out.println(b);
            } else {
                flag = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```